# MaterializeCSS select() method doesn't work on IOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, dom, materialize

I have been working on [materializecss.com](https://materializecss.com/tabs.html) to build a web app by using the google script platform but while everything works well under Windows, Linux, Android, it doesn't work on IOS (except chrome/firefox only on MAC). The problem seems to be related to `.select();` method of Tabs structures. More specifically when enabling a particular tab by using `instance.select('tab_id');` the ios devices redirect you to a new window instead of enabling the tab.

Is there any good solution to this? A sample code can be seen below.

```
    <nav class="nav-extended">
       <div class="nav-content">
         <ul id="navBarTabs" class="tabs">
           <li id="TabId1" class="tab"><a href="#tab1">TAB1</a></li>
           <li id="TabId2" class="tab disabled"><a href="#tab2">TAB2</a></li>     
         </ul>
       </div>
      </nav>
```

```
</script>
M.Tabs.init(document.getElementById("navBarTabs")).select("tab2");
</script>
```

The HTML page is rendered with this option:

```
HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("fileName").getContent().evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in iOS, one solution is to serve a patched `select.js` after materialize.js.

So like this:

```
<script src="/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/select.js"></script>
<script src="/js/yourcustom.js"></script>
```

Here is the patched select.js file: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/js/select.js